# Opencart 2.3 order history comment in order list

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Task: need to show last admin comment (order history) to a order list page.
Add to a admin/controller/sale in function getList() $data['orders'][] = array code

```
'admin_comments'     => $this->model_sale_order->getOrderHistories('sale/order_history', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&order_id=' . $result['order_id'])
```

But it does not work. How do I correctly get an array with the history of each order?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing building a URL with calling a function.  You just need the latter.

```
'admin_comments'     => $this->model_sale_order->getOrderHistories(
                           $result['order_id']);
```